# special table in latex

Tags: tables

I would like to make a table like this in the image please can someone tell how I can do that[image]

```
    \begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}}
\cline{2-10}
&\multicolumn{3}{|c|} {\bf $N_{min}$ Amis }& \multicolumn{3}{|c|} {\bf $N_{moy}$ Amis  }& \multicolumn{3}{|c|} {\bf $N_{max}$ Amis }\\ %\multicolumn{2}{|p{2.5cm}|} {\bf 750 Pages }& %\multicolumn{2}{|p{2.5cm}|} {\bf 1000 Pages }\\
\cline{2-10}
& \bf AS& \bf A\& A & \bf Pub& \bf AS& \bf A\& A & \bf Pub & \bf AS & \bf A\& A & \bf Pub \\
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$N_{moy}$ Amis} &\bf 25.66& \bf 26.66& \bf 27&\bf 33& \bf 33& \bf 33& \bf 39.66& \bf 39.66& \bf 39.5\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{3.5cm}|}{Moy Pages cibles } &\bf 25.66& \bf 62& \bf 100& \bf 33& \bf 71.33& \bf 100& \bf 39.66& \bf 80.33& \bf 100\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\bf{\caption{Partager Publication dans le réseau 1}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: but the code that I propose is right but it is missing a column in the left before Nmoy Min and Nb Pages cibles

Comment: I modify the image do you understand what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is virtually impossible to rela
te your image to the posted code, but anyway I offer this, if it is not what you need then please edit the question to make it clearer. Also please note that `\bf` is an obsolete command (and even when used never takes an argument. It is not `\bf{...}` but `{\bf ...}` or better `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}



\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\bfseries

\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{11}{p{.8cm}|}}
\cline{3-11}
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|} { $N_{min}$ Amis }& \multicolumn{3}{c|} { $N_{moy}$ Amis  }& \multicolumn{3}{c|} { $N_{max}$ Amis }\\ 
\cline{3-11}
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}&  AS&  A\&A &  Pub&  AS&  A\&A &  Pub &  AS &  A\&A &  Pub \\
\hline
\raisebox{-5pt}{xxx}&$N_{moy}$ Amis & 25.66&  26.66&  27& 33&  33&  33&  39.66&  39.66&  39.5\\
\cline{2-11}
 &Moy Pages cibles & 25.66&  62&  100&  33&  71.33&  100&  39.66&  80.33&  100\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-2cm}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: the code that you suggest gives the same result of the code that I proposed. But I want that before the two columns entitled N moyAmis Nb pages cibles we add a new cell that contain Num Réseau

Comment: the code here fits on the page unlike the code in the question, how was anyone supposed to deduce that you wanted an extra cell with some text that doesn't appear anywhere in the question? I still have no idea where you want that text to appear. I suggest that you take the image from my answer and edit it in a bitmap editor and just add the text you want at the right place. that way we might have a clue, and can update the code to match.

Comment: Also do you want the numbers set flush left or do you want them aligned on the decimal point?

Comment: I don't know the difference betewen them but if it is necessary I want in the center of cell

Comment: I edit the image I hope that you can understand me now.

Comment: The image in the question  still bears no resemblance to the code especially the second row with each column split in to three. That's why I suggested you edit the image from the answer.

Comment: ok this what I want but I want also in the image the second column which is after what you put(XXX) I want that is column is divided into two rows.

Comment: like that? I changed 3 to 2 in the \cline

Comment: :Please I want to enlarge the size of my cells how I can do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3390/discussion-between-boutheina-and-david-carlisle)

Comment: Can someone answer me please?